# Objective-c networking on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, networking, ios4

I would like to connect to a server on tcp/ip to the port 65000 from my iPhone app. I tried to read about CFNetwork sockets and the connecting documentation, but didn't success with these helps. Can you point me to the right way please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [AsyncSocket](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AsyncSocket) class. It's an easy-to-use Objective-C wrapper class for CFNetwork and works flawless and painless. I use it in a lot of my projects and I couldn't recommend it more.